# Turning led off after 30 seconds

Tags: avr

Hi I'm driving some leds using bs170 mosfet. The led's are lighting up however I would like to be able to turn it off after 30 seconds say.  I tried using the following code but it didn't work. I think it's turning off and on faster than I notice. I seem to be getting a square wave on the scope on the pin that the fet is connected to.

```
/*
 * AVRGCC1.c
 * 
 * Created: 21/04/2011 21:38:56
 *  Author: steven
 */ 

#define F_CPU 20000000UL  // 1 MHz 

#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void)
{ 
        //TODO:: Please write your application code 
        DDRA=0b00000001; //Make PDA0 as output  
        PORTA =0b00000001; // turn on fet  
        _delay_ms(30000);
        DDRA=0b00000000;
}
```

Comment: the comment 20000000UL  // 1MHz seems inaccurate :)

Comment: lol yeah I didn't change the comment. Originally the example was for the internal oscillator.  I'm a lazy bugger lool.

Comment: can you look up the source to the _delay_ms() function/macro?  I suspect you are overflowing something inside there.

Comment: It's bad style to let execution flow to the end of main() in an embedded processor.  There's nothing to return to.  So add a "while (1);" at the end to loop forever.

Comment: I prefer for(;;){}

Answer (score 6):

This part ..

```
PORTA =0b00000001; // turn on fet 
_delay_ms(30000);
DDRA=0b00000000;
```

should probably look like this ..

```
PORTA =0b00000001; // turn on fet 
_delay_ms(30000);
PORTA=0b00000000;
```

i.e., you don't want to redefine the direction of the pin, you want to change its state.

Comment: Jeff, i concur with your assessment

Comment: If you have a pull-down on the mosfet gate, both options would work. However, if you just let it float, setting the pin to an input would cause it to behave in an unspecified manner.

Comment: actually switching it to input with the port set to one enables the internal pullup, so the output would in effect always be high.

Answer (score 3):

Plus, instead of overwriting the whole Port, it is generally better to modify only the affected bit (pin). This can be done by

Set Pin x to "high":

```
PORTA |= (1 << x);
```

Set Pin x to "low":

```
PORTA &= ~(1 << x);
```

Especially if mutliple parts are connected to the port, this method is way safer. The same can be done with the DDRx register, if you only want to modify the direction of single Pins.

Comment: avr-gcc has a macro _BV(x) for doing this sort of thing too, fyi... _BV(1) == 0b00000001, _BV(2) == 0b00000010, etc...